# How to use anyother map like google maps in UIWebView in iphone?

Tags: javascript, iphone, google-maps, uiwebview

I have done google map in UIWebView and it works perfectly with routing stuff and all. But now i want to load some other map into the WebView and get all the features that i get from google maps. How can i do it?

For eg: I want to load this one to the UIWebView. http://stage.discoveritalia.it/conbipel/ .This is an italian map. I want to use it in the same way as google maps works in an iphone app. Plz help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using normal web-based Google Maps in a UIWebView and not UIMapKit you approach this as any other Google Maps implementation using JavaScript.

The way this is done is by defining a custom map tile layer. See the [Google Maps API documentation for custom tiles](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/overlays.html#CustomMapTiles) for more information.

Note that beside the actual programming, you need to have (and the rights to use) the actual map tiles as well.

Comment: For google-maps, what i do is that I save this http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/examples/map-simple.htmlMIMEType as an html file. 
Then
      NSString *htmlPath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"map" ofType:@"html"];
 NSData *htmlData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:htmlPath];
 [map loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/"]];

After that parsing with th javascript gives me the result.

I think I should change the html file that I use. If you got any idea, plz help me.